# Trust anchors not found only on device but running on emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, anchor, okhttp

Everything is in the title, i don't understand why my code works in the emulator but not on my device. It throws an "trust anchors not found exception" ! How can it be possible ? I tried the implementation of okhttp.builder about trustManager but still.. Help Please !!

Here is my class :

```
public abstract class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAAG = NewsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    protected ItemAdapter mArticleAdapter;
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected NewsFragment.OnNewSelectedInterface mListener;
    protected ItemAdapter.OnNewsInsertedInterface mListener2;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mManager;
    protected SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    public static final String KEY_LIST = "key_list";

    public interface OnNewSelectedInterface {
        void onListNewSelected(int index, ArrayList<Article> articles);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_present_news, container, false);

        mListener = (NewsFragment.OnNewSelectedInterface) getActivity();
        mListener2 = (ItemAdapter.OnNewsInsertedInterface) getActivity();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mArticleAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<>(), mListener, mListener2);

        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) alertUserAboutError();

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        new Downloader().execute(getUrl());
        //new Downloader().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, getUrl());

        refreshData();

        setDividerRecyclerView();

        return view;
    }

    private void setDividerRecyclerView() {
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView
                .getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        alertDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }

    protected abstract String[] getUrl();

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void refreshData() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            mArticleAdapter.clear();
            new Downloader().execute(getUrl());
        });

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    }

    private class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Article>> {

        ArrayList<Article> mArticleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient();


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Article> doInBackground(String... strings) {

            for (String aMUrl : getUrl()) {
                Request mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(aMUrl).build();
                try {
                    Response response = mClient.newCall(mRequest).execute();
                    try {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            String json = response.body().string();
                            mArticleArrayList = getMultipleUrls(json);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return mArticleArrayList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Article> articles) {
            mArticleAdapter.addAll(articles);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            Log.v(TAAG, String.valueOf(mArticleAdapter.getItemCount()));
        }

        private ArrayList<Article> getMultipleUrls(String jsonData) throws JSONException {

            if (mArticleArrayList == null || mArticleArrayList.size() == 0) {
                mArticleArrayList = getArticleForecast(jsonData);
            } else {
                mArticleArrayList.addAll(getArticleForecast(jsonData));
            }

            return mArticleArrayList;
        }

        private ArrayList<Article> getArticleForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
            JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray articles = forecast.getJSONArray("articles");

            ArrayList<Article> listArticles = new ArrayList<>(articles.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonArticle = articles.getJSONObject(i);
                Article article = new Article();

                String urlImage = jsonArticle.getString("urlToImage");

                article.setTitle(jsonArticle.getString("title"));
                article.setDescription(jsonArticle.getString("description"));
                article.setImageView(urlImage);
                article.setArticleUrl(jsonArticle.getString("url"));
                article.setUrlToImage(jsonArticle.getString("urlToImage"));

                listArticles.add(i, article);
            }

            return listArticles;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the log :

```
05-04 23:39:01.382 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
05-04 23:39:01.382 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:306)
05-04 23:39:01.382 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:242)
05-04 23:39:01.382 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:200)
05-04 23:39:01.382 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:174)
05-04 23:39:01.382 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:114)
05-04 23:39:01.382 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:196)
05-04 23:39:01.382 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:132)
05-04 23:39:01.382 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:101)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at com.silho.ideo.knewsproject.Fragments.PresentNews.NewsFragment$Downloader.doInBackground(NewsFragment.java:170)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at com.silho.ideo.knewsproject.Fragments.PresentNews.NewsFragment$Downloader.doInBackground(NewsFragment.java:143)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-04 23:39:01.383 9856-9997/com.silho.ideo.knewsproject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I also found this on the okhttp site but it doesn't work also :

public OkHttpClient.Builder sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory,
                                             X509TrustManager trustManager)
Sets the socket factory and trust manager used to secure HTTPS connections. If unset, the system defaults will be used.
Most applications should not call this method, and instead use the system defaults. Those classes include special optimizations that can be lost if the implementations are decorated.

If necessary, you can create and configure the defaults yourself with the following code:

```
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
       TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
   trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
   TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
   if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
     throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
         + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
   }
   X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];

   SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
   sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);
   SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
       .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager);
       .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my android app (and with my Spring Boot back-end server). I think your problem is related to the fact that you are using a  self-signed certificate. The solution is to embed in the assets folder of your app a trust manager(in a PKCS12 format) containing the trusted certificate.

**1.** Add your keystore with the certificate in the assets folder:

[image: Trust store location]

**2.** Then configue the OkHttpClient with your embedded trust manager in this way:
(change the password with your)

```
fun getOkHttpClient(context: Context): OkHttpClient {

val password = "keystore_password".toCharArray()

val keyStore = KeyStore
    .getInstance("PKCS12").apply {
        load(context.assets.open("trust_store.p12"), password)
    }

val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
    .apply { init(keyStore) }

val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory
    .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
    .apply { init(keyStore, password) }

val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
    .apply {
        init(keyManagerFactory.keyManagers, trustManagerFactory.trustManagers, SecureRandom())
    }

return OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory,
        trustManagerFactory.trustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager)
    .hostnameVerifier { hostname, _ -> hostname == apiHostname } // Return true if you want to trust all hostnames
    .build()

}
```

If you want to trust all hostnames, simply return true in the `hostnameVerifier` function block, but i don't recommend you to do so, since it can expose your app to security threats.

Note that using a custom trust store, ***your app will trust only the certificates contained in that trust store.***